# The Boostrap 5 navbar cannot be closed once it is opened

Tags: bootstrap-5

My navbar menu and navbrand are not working/clickable in my `index.html` but are functional on my other pages. The navbar code is exactly the same as the other 4 pages, and all 4 are perfectly fine apart from my `index.html` file page.

I am using Gitpod as my IDE.

This is my code:

```html
<!-- Navbar -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark navbar-expand-sm">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand">Visa Chronicles</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item mr-2"><a class="nav-link active" href="index.html" aria-current="true">Home</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item mr-2"><a class="nav-link" href="mystory.html" aria-current="page">My Story</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item mr-2"><a class="nav-link" href="visaprocess.html" aria-current="page">Visa Process</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item mr-2"><a class="nav-link" href="documents.html" aria-current="page">Documents</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item mr-2"><a class="nav-link" href="contact.html" aria-current="page">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kit.fontawesome.com/481d34bf91.js" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-IQsoLXl5PILFhosVNubq5LC7Qb9DXgDA9i+tQ8Zj3iwWAwPtgFTxbJ8NT4GN1R8p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cVKIPhGWiC2Al4u+LWgxfKTRIcfu0JTxR+EQDz/bgldoEyl4H0zUF0QKbrJ0EcQF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/481d34bf91.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason why the navbar cannot be closed once opened is that you added the Bootstrap JS bundle **and** then also Bootstrap JS and Popper JS separately. The bundle already includes everything you need.

Either you do this...

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

...or you do this.

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-IQsoLXl5PILFhosVNubq5LC7Qb9DXgDA9i+tQ8Zj3iwWAwPtgFTxbJ8NT4GN1R8p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cVKIPhGWiC2Al4u+LWgxfKTRIcfu0JTxR+EQDz/bgldoEyl4H0zUF0QKbrJ0EcQF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

See the snippet below.

```html
<!-- Navbar -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark navbar-expand-sm">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand">Visa Chronicles</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item mr-2"><a class="nav-link active" href="index.html" aria-current="true">Home</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item mr-2"><a class="nav-link" href="mystory.html" aria-current="page">My Story</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item mr-2"><a class="nav-link" href="visaprocess.html" aria-current="page">Visa Process</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item mr-2"><a class="nav-link" href="documents.html" aria-current="page">Documents</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item mr-2"><a class="nav-link" href="contact.html" aria-current="page">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kit.fontawesome.com/481d34bf91.js" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```